How to calculate percentile on array with conditions and value errors with Excel?
I have an array comprised of both numbers and value errors, and I want to calculate a percentile value from numbers (excluding the errors) in the set where certain conditions are met in another array of the same length.
As a first step, this formula works to reduce the applicable set to values that are numbers:
=PERCENTILE(IF(ISNUMBER(D13:D3637),D13:D3637),0.50)

So I expected to be able to add conditions with an AND function like this:
=PERCENTILE(IF(AND(C13:C3637<N12,ISNUMBER(D13:D3637)),D13:D3637),0.50)

But the AND function does not seem to work here (it seems to apply to the whole arrays, rather than on an element-by-element basis).

=PERCENTILE(IF((C13:C3637<N12)*(ISNUMBER(D13:D3637)),D13:D3637),0.50) perhaps?

Excellor, that's better than my answer. Make it an answer, and I'll accept it. Thank you for your help!

You can use =PERCENTILE(IF((C13:C3637<N12)*(ISNUMBER(D13:D3637)),D13:D3637),0.50)
Breakdown:
(C13:C3637<N12) is a statement within the first argument of your IF function and will return TRUE or FALSE
(ISNUMBER(D13:D3637) is the second statement, and will also return TRUE or FALSE.
Excel can see TRUE and FALSE as 1 and 0; thus multiplying them will result also in  1 or 0.
Sidenote:
You can use different operators, for different logic types:  * means AND, while + means OR. There's also the use of /, but I'm uncertain how that works. (Where any return number, except 0 will return TRUE for the IF function.)

Second option is the use of BITAND, but it only holds two arguments, and there are some other limitations.

Ok, I got it. Nest the conditions as follows:
=PERCENTILE(
IF(<condition 1>,
IF(<condition 2>,
...
IF(<condition n>,
<array>)...)),<percentile>)

So in my case:
=PERCENTILE(
IF(C$13:C$3637>=$M12,
IF(C$13:C$3637<N12,
IF(ISNUMBER(D$13:D$3637),
D$13:D$3637))),0.5)

